# Dispatch action in effect before return statement

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I need to dispatch/trigger another ui-related action inside an effect before calling the service to fetch data without injecting the store

I managed to fix it by injecting the store in the constructor and dispatch this extra action in effect right before calling the service for fetching the data(`this.store.dispatch(UIActions.startLoading()`) but I am not sure if injecting the store in the effect is a good practice

```
recipes$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(RecipeActions.FETCH_RECIPES),
        switchMap(() => this.recipeService.getRecipes().pipe(
            switchMap(recipes => [
                RecipeActions.setRecipes({ recipes }),
                UIActions.stopLoading()
            ]),
            catchError(() => EMPTY)
        ))
    ));
```

I wonder if there is a way to do this like using
`tap(() => of(UIActions.startLoading()))` inside the first `switchMap`

Comment: switchMap is used to dispatch multiple actions just like you did, I dont see a problem

Comment: I want to integrate UIActions.startLoading() into the effect as well before calling the service

Comment: Add an other switchMap before the service call and dispatch your action there

Comment: I ended up injecting the store as It did not go well to put another swithMap in between

`ofType(RecipeActions.FETCH_RECIPES),`
`this.store.dispatch(UIActions.startLoading()`
`...`

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in the use of `tap` operator for your desired functionality.

However, you need to do `store.dispatch` instead of simply returning an `of` observable.
Also, instead of multiple `switchMap`, you can use the `from` observable to return array of `actions`.

```
recipes$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(RecipeActions.FETCH_RECIPES),
        tap(()=> this.store.dispatch(UIActions.startLoading())),
        switchMap(() => this.recipeService.getRecipes().pipe(
            map(recipes => from([
                RecipeActions.setRecipes({ recipes }),
                UIActions.stopLoading()
            ]),
            catchError(() => EMPTY)
        ))
    ));
```